# Ubuntu 16.04, manually deleted library, couldn't install using apt-get for gdal library

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, uninstall

I was working on GDAL library.

I installed it using `apt-get install` then lib is installed to `/usr/share/gdal` folder (gdal 1.11). Then I need to upgrade to new version (gdal 2.1.3) and I added a repo to source.list (`ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable`) to get new version.

I delete `/usr/share/gdal` folder by mistake. Then I try to install using `apt-get install`, it never creates this folder (`/usr/share/gdal`).

Also I tried to delete everything, `usr/share/gdal`, `usr/include/gdal`, `apt-get remove`... Then I try to reinstall, again it fails.

I will be glad for any help.

Comment: Fixed!
Uninstall everything,
Remove newly added repo,
Install old version, then add new repo,
Upgrade library

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you solved your own problem, please consider to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-)

Comment: ok, I will check it  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `dpkg-query --search` to find the affected packages that have (or had) files installed to a particular path, e. g.

   ```sh
   dpkg-query --search /usr/share/gdal/
   ```
2. Restore the corrupted packages via Apt with the `--reinstall` option, e. g.

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgdal1i
   ```

With some output mangling you can combine those commands without a manual intermediate step:

```sh
dpkg-query --search /usr/share/gdal/ | sed -e 's/:.*//;s/, /\n/g' | sort -u | xargs -r -- sudo apt-get install --reinstall
```